# Sort order guarantee for key (value) argument of CouchDB reduce function?

Tags: couchdb, reduce

As you know, the `reduce` function in CouchDB views looks like this:

```js
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
}
```

where the definition of first arguments is as follows:

> when rereduce is `false`, then:
>
> 1. key will be an array whose elements are arrays of the form [key,id], where key is a key emitted by the map function and id is that of the document from which the key was generated.
> 2. values will be an array of the values emitted for the respective elements in keys.

My question is: when rereduce is `false`, are there any guarantees regarding the order of `key` (or `values`) array elements? My gut feel (based on [Reduce vs Rereduce](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_vs_rereduce) chapter) is that keys, and respectively values, should be ordered, but I do not see any direct confirmation.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

From https://cloudant.com/for-developers/all_docs/

```
Sort Order

All indexes are sorted by their key. The sort order is:

null
false
true
numbers
text, cases sensitive - lower case first
arrays, sorted element by element
objects
```

The full specification is documented in the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Collation_Specification).

Comment: I thought the question was about the order of `values` with elements for a single step for computation, not the index.